# How to use Formik's handleChange multiple times to change the same value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, formik

I use Material-UI and Formik. I want that two input fields can edit a single value. In this case there is a TextField and a Slider and both of those inputs should allow to change the value for the `perdiod`. When I give both input fields the same id I get the following error message, which I kinda expected: *Formik cannot determine which value to update*

But is there a way to do that with Formik or do I need to write a custom handleChange function?

```js
const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      period: 5,
    },
```

```html
<OutlinedInput
 id="period"
 name="period"
 type="period"
 onChange={formik.handleChange}
 value={formik.values.period}
/>


<Slider 
  value={formik.values.period}
  aria-label="Default" 
  min={0}
  max={20}
  id="period"
  onChange={formik.handleChange}
/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dont give them the same id ,
but give them the same name